Plot is incomplete not reaching all bars
I am plotting the weekly hlc3 average for 3 weeks as a weekly overlay on a daily chart but it doesn't plot through each day of the week.
My script on PineScript v5 is as follows:
//@version=5

indicator("WeeklyZones",timeframe="1W",overlay=true)

wP3= avg(hlc3[0]+hlc3[1]+hlc3[2])

plot(wP3,color=color.red,offset=1)

It generates the plot as seen on the following image.  Note how the weekly overlay (ie. White Line) doesn't go through the days as current week is developing.
Example
I need my plotted line to go through the day of the week as the days progress.  My script seems to fully plot the line only when the week has ended.

Try request.security; something like that:
//@version=5

indicator("WeeklyZones",overlay=true)

wP3= math.avg(hlc3[0],hlc3[1],hlc3[2])
wp3HTF  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '1W', wP3)

plot(wp3HTF,color=color.red,offset=1)

